# Why am I getting NoClassDefFoundError on JSONObject in amazon-kinesis-client?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I've incorporated the code from DynamoDB streams adapter demo from aws-dynamodb-examples, into my Maven project, and I'm getting a run-time error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/util/json/JSONObject
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.leases.impl.Lease.toString(Lease.java:229)
```

Any idea why this happens and what I can do to fix it?

My pom file is this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.aligntech</groupId>
  <artifactId>dynamodbstream</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>dynamodbstream</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
          <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
          <version>LATEST</version>
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>dynamodb-streams-kinesis-adapter</artifactId>
      <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Try adding a dependency on `aws-java-sdk-core`

Comment: Tried it. No luck. I see that aws-java-sdk-core, in its latest version, doesn't have the class com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject. I wonder where it went?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Siguza

Answer (score 9):

The problem is resolved if I change the version of `aws-java-sdk` to `1.10.77`.
It seems that the kinesis library in version 1.11.0 is trying to use JSONObject which has been removed from `com.amazonaws.util.json`.

Comment: The aws-java-sdk is currently at 2.0 and I am having this problem still.  What version should I be at now to stop having this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this configuration. Works for me and I think this is the correct way of doing it. With this configuration you are aligned with latest AWS versions.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.0.RC2"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk"
    }

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.11.197'
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.197'
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'amazon-kinesis-client', version: '1.8.1'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```